# Angularfire - Only write to Firestore on the first OAuth (Google, facebook) login

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, angularfire

packages:

- `"@angular/cdk": "~10.0.0",`
- `"@angular/fire": "^6.0.5",`
- `"firebase": "^8.0.0",`

I have an Angular application with Firebase as a serverless backend solution. Users can register and login through Firebase Auth using their Facebook or Google Accounts. After they successfully login, I store their information (displayName, createdAt, contactEmail) in Firestore.

This is the method I use:

```js
  public async googleLogin(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
      const response = await this.afAuth.signInWithPopup(provider);

      return this.afStore.create(response.user.uid,
        {
          id: response.user.uid,
          contactEmail: response.user.email,
          displayName: response.user.displayName,
          createdAt: this._userDB.createTimestamp()
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  }
```

However, my problem is that every time the user logs in, this function will be called and subsequently previously set fields like displayName, createdAt and contactEmail will be overwritten. I´ve no idea how to check in Firebase Auth if the user is new or just logs in again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the credential (your `const response` variable), you can access to `response.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser` [to know if it is a new user or not](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#additionaluserinfo). Create the user if true or do nothing otherwise:

```js
  public async googleLogin(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
      const response = await this.afAuth.signInWithPopup(provider);
      // return an empty promise if user is not new
      if (!response.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) { return Promise.resolve(); }
      return this.afStore.create(response.user.uid,
        {
          id: response.user.uid,
          contactEmail: response.user.email,
          displayName: response.user.displayName,
          createdAt: this._userDB.createTimestamp()
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Ah, it´s so easy. Thank you for the quick answer.